# "Invalid column name" error when calling insert after table created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I'm developing SQL script, using SSMS, which makes some changes in database:

```
USE MyDatabase;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- some statements

PRINT(N'#1');

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = N'Table1' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Table2_Id'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2_Table2_Id];
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] DROP COLUMN [Table2_Id];
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table2];

    PRINT(N'Table2 was dropped.');
END

PRINT(N'#2');

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = N'Table2'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
    (
        [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        [Number] INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        [RowVersion] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    );
PRINT(N'Table2 was re-created.');
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2]([Number], [Name]) VALUES(-1, N'Default value');
PRINT(N'Default value was inserted in Table2.');
END

-- some statements

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

If `Table1` has a column, named `Table2_Id`, then database has two tables (`Table1` and `Table2`) and a foreign key relationship between them. In that case, I need to:

- drop foreign key relationship `FK_Table1_Table2_Table2_Id`;
- drop foreign key column `Table1.Table2_Id`;
- drop `Table2`;
- re-create `Table2`, using new table schema;
- insert some default value in `Table2`.

When I'm trying to execute this script, I'm getting these errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 262 Invalid column name 'Number'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 262 Invalid column name 'Name'.

Looks like SQL Server uses old schema for `Table2` (which indeed hasn't these columns), but how is this possible, if the table has just created with new schema?

What am I doing wrong?

Server version is SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64).

**UPDATE**.

I've added `PRINT` calls (see script above). There's nothing in message window, except error messages. So, the script isn't being executed... What's going on??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQL Server tries to compile the whole batch. If the table already exists then it will compile according to the pre-existing definition. The statement referencing the new columns doesn't compile and so the batch never executes.

You need to group the statements using the new definition into a new batch. If you are running this in SSMS just insert a `GO`

```
USE MyDatabase;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- some statements

PRINT(N'#1');

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = N'Table1' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Table2_Id'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2_Table2_Id];
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] DROP COLUMN [Table2_Id];
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table2];

    PRINT(N'Table2 was dropped.');
END

GO

PRINT(N'#2');

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = N'Table2'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
    (
        [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        [Number] INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        [RowVersion] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    );
PRINT(N'Table2 was re-created.');
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2]([Number], [Name]) VALUES(-1, N'Default value');
PRINT(N'Default value was inserted in Table2.');
END

COMMIT
```

Otherwise you could run the offending line in a child batch

```
    EXEC(N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2]([Number], [Name]) VALUES(-1, N''Default value'');')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... This - "If the table already exists then it will compile according to the pre-existing definition" - is a most stupid and not obvious strategy I ever could imagine... `GO` isn't a good option, the script is rather large, and there are some variables, declared at the top of script, that used widely in entire script. Anyway, thanks, I'll think about workaround.

Comment: @Dennis If you do not want to lose your variables, then I would suggest splitting the different batches (dropping / creating tables ) into separate stored procedures, then wrapping those in a main stored procedure.