# “Invalid column name” sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that i added a new column to. The column name is LocationKey. Whenever i try and use that column in a alter stored procedure i get a error message below. I went back and copy pasted the column name. It is exact! it is where it needs to be on both tables.

```
 Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_MY_Stored_procedure, Line 122
Invalid column name 'LocationKey'.
```

I have googled and nothing that i came up with has resolved the problem. What could i be missing?

Link i have read:
1. ["Invalid column name" error when calling insert after table created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165803/invalid-column-name-error-when-calling-insert-after-table-created)

2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87ef4b02-6a57-4cae-9e0c-bf705f3c2bec/invalid-column-name-after-adding-new-column
3. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/

Anything i can try to troubleshoot this further would be greatly appreciated.

```
-- DROP LEADING DOUBLE QUOTE (and PhotoUrl column)
    INSERT INTO [table2](

        [Comment1]
        ,[Comment 2]
        ,[Comment 3]
        ,[Comment 4]
        ,[Name]
        ,[PhotoUrl]
        ,[LocationKey]

        )



    SELECT 
         [Comment1]
        , [Comment 2]
        , [Comment 3]
        , [Comment 4]
        , SUBSTRING([Name],1,100)-- Limit to 100 chars
        , [PhotoUrl]  -- varchar(MAX)
        , [LocationKey]


    FROM [table1]
```

Comment: Please show us your table definition and your query where you get an error

Comment: Does column "LocationKey" exists in table?

Comment: can you post the SQL?

Comment: I am sorry if am writing false things .. but can you please post your actual query .. it will be more helpfull

Comment: @jackncoke do you add the column and attempt to use it right away after adding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the comma issue in the other answers is just a typo in your question, two other thoughts come to mind:

1. Is your SP switching to a different database that possibly has the same table structure (but wasn't updated)?
2. Do you have multiple copies of the database (development, production, etc), and you added the column to a different server than where you are trying to change the SP?

Also, you can copy and paste your SELECT statement to a new query, and try running it.  That will tell you if the invalid column error is coming from Table1 or Table2.

Another thought - are you possibly querying through a view, and not direct to the table?  If the view isn't defined with SCHEMABINDING, you'll need to refresh the view to have the new field appear.

Comment: I agree - it's unlikely to be something more sinister. Think simple first!

Comment: Thank you! I had a miss reference to a production table that should of been a development table.

Comment: @jackncoke, you can use colour coding for the environments, check out this link http://evanon.net/blog/post/2011/04/16/Colour-coded-Environments-in-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2008.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the SQL, since the syntax looks incorrect, try this...

```
INSERT INTO [table2](

        [Comment1]
        ,[Comment 2]
        ,[Comment 3]
        ,[Comment 4]
        ,[Name]
        ,[PhotoUrl]
        ,[LocationKey]

        )



    SELECT 
         [Comment1]
        , [Comment 2]
        , [Comment 3]
        , [Comment 4]
        , SUBSTRING([Name],1,100)-- Limit to 100 chars
        , [PhotoUrl]  -- varchar(MAX)
        , [LocationKey]


    FROM [table1]
```

EDIT: Based on comments

If you want to colour code the different environments, you can use this tip http://evanon.net/blog/post/2011/04/16/Colour-coded-Environments-in-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2008.aspx

Comment: You're missing an open bracket on the second line (the insert statement).

Comment: There was a error in my syntax after i copied it to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.  Remove leading commas, add parenthesis.  See updated code below.

```
INSERT INTO [table2]
(
  [Comment1]
 ,[Comment 2]
 ,[Comment 3]
 ,[Comment 4]
 ,[Name]
 ,[PhotoUrl]
 ,[LocationKey]
)

SELECT
  [Comment1]
 ,[Comment 2]
 ,[Comment 3]
 ,[Comment 4]
 ,SUBSTRING([Name],1,100)
 ,[PhotoUrl]
 ,[LocationKey]
FROM [table1];
```

Comment: There was a error in my syntax after i copied it to shorten it.