# Inserting into table A from table B, giving invalid column name error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `A` which holds the columns (`test1`, `test2`, `test3`) and then table `B` which holds the columns (`test4`, `test5`, `test6`).

Table `B`, column `test6` was added in after the table was created by using

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.B
    ADD test6 VARCHAR(100)
```

I want to do:

```
INSERT dbo.A (test1, test2, test3)
SELECT test4, test5, test6
FROM dbo.B
```

It keeps coming back saying that `test6` is an `"Invalid Column Name"`. Could it be something to do with adding the table in using the `ALTER TABLE` statement?

Table `A`, the one I'm inserting into is `PK` constrained, I'm not sure if that's relevant, though.

Comment: Check the columns of your table using `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'B'   AND table_schema = 'dbo''`

Comment: you are missing into keyword

Comment: @sqlProfile87: no, he is not missing that keyword - it's **optional** , you don't *have to* use it. [See the MSDN docs on INSERT for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Invalid column name" error when calling insert after table created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165803/invalid-column-name-error-when-calling-insert-after-table-created)

Answer (score 1):

Are both tasks written in one SQL-script? In that case I'd recommend you to add a GO-statement between these tasks.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.B
    ADD test6 VARCHAR(100)
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.A (test1, test2, test3)
SELECT test4, test5, test6
FROM dbo.B
```

If this is not working either, use the following task to check if the colum exists.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.B
```