# Invalid column name during Insert Into

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't for the life of me figure out why I get an error of "Invalid column name 'AvgDaily'" on the following code.  Any ideas?

```
create table #TMP_Daily_Avg_Rollup 
(
     Zone varchar(20), 
     fkiItem int, 
     fkiLocation int, 
     AvgDaily decimal(12,3)
)

Insert into #TMP_Daily_Avg_Rollup (Zone, fkiItem, fkiLocation, AvgDaily)
    Select
        tte.Zone, tte.fkiItem, tte.fkiLocation, 
        (sum(tte.TransQty) / @UsageDaysLong) as AvgDaily
    From
        #TMP_Trans_Events tte
    Group By 
        tte.Zone, tte.fkiItem, tte.fkiLocation
    Order By 
        tte.fkiItem
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Cannot reproduce your case [demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=554aedba8c1e3b139f090ac216141d3a)

Comment: Using MS-SQL   Error message is Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 154
Invalid column name 'DailyAvg'.

Comment: DailyAvg != AvgDaily. There is no `DailyAvg` in your snippet

Comment: Your script doesn't have column `DailyAvg`.  So where's the error coming from?????

Comment: Sorry, been trying other names just in case.  The error was for AvgDaily

Comment: I can't identify the error, but you could try dropping the temp table then writing:  `SELECT ... INTO #TMP_Daily_Avg_Rollup FROM...` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Invalid column name" error when calling insert after table created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165803/invalid-column-name-error-when-calling-insert-after-table-created)

Answer (score 0):

very wild guess

Lose the outer parentheses marks, column aliases in your SELECT, and table alias as we're only selecting from one table

```
INSERT INTO #TMP_Daily_Avg_Rollup (Zone, fkiItem, fkiLocation, AvgDaily)
SELECT Zone, fkiItem, fkiLocation, sum(TransQty) / @UsageDaysLong
FROM #TMP_Trans_Events 
GROUP BY Zone, fkiItem, fkiLocation
ORDER BY fkiItem
```

As an aside..

- Do you really need the ORDER BY to insert rows into your temp table?
- What's the column data type of TransQty and UsageDaysLong?  If you expect an expression return values with three decimal places you'll want to make sure that one of those values also has three decimal places.

Comment: Qualified column names are a best practice.  This is really bad advice and has nothing to do with the question, given that `AvgDaily` is not even selected in the `SELECT` portion of the query.

Comment: Qualified column names in a SELECT are not relevant when the overall query is an INSERT, as the ordering of column position between the INSERT and SELECT is enforced.

Comment: TransQty is a Decimal and UsageDaysLong is a tinyint

Comment: When you click on the error message the cursor will jump to the offending line.  Which line does it jump to, the CREATE TABLE, or the INSERT?

Comment: It jumps to the Insert line

Comment: Hmm.  Not seeing anything that would cause this error message.  Please re-post your current code.