# Msg 207, Level 16, State 1 "Invalid column name 'Name'"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to drop and recreate a table with a new schema in SQL Server, and then insert some test data into it to validate that it's working correctly. I have the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    [Modified] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()),
    [ModifiedBy] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

and the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([Name], [Description], [Modified], [ModifiedBy])
VALUES('Test', 'Description', GETUTCDATE(), 'Me');
```

Whenever I attempt to insert the aforementioned row, I get an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
>   Invalid column name 'Name'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
>   Invalid column name 'Description'.

I know the table is there since I can `SELECT * FROM Product` and get an empty result set with the correct columns and no errors... I just can't insert into it for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please use fully qualified names - most likely it is table from different schema/database

Comment: If you are trying to drop and recreate it and the original table didn't have these columns you will need to divide it into batches. You can't have the `DROP`, `CREATE` and `INSERT` referencing the new columns all in the same batch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Martin's answer, I did some more research and he is correct. The schema manipulation needs to be done in separate batches (I simply added a `GO` after dropping my old table and after creating my new one with a different schema). A more detailed answer can be found here: ["Invalid column name" error when calling insert after table created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165803/invalid-column-name-error-when-calling-insert-after-table-created)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try refreshing the cache. Easy way is to press Ctrl + shift + R

Or

```
Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache
```

If doesnt work, then use qualified names [dbo].table or username.tablename etc

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx

Comment: An upvote because this actually helped me get a correct error message referencing the correct line (refreshing the cache).

Answer (score 0):

For me, your query looks good, and i test it successfully.

Try adding schema name and put all column name inside brackets:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    [Modified] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()),
    [ModifiedBy] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([Name], [Description], [Modified], [ModifiedBy])
VALUES('Test', 'Description', GETUTCDATE(), 'Me');
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't do anything just try to insert (' ')single quotes instead of (") quotes.. or if you insert data with ('')single quotes try for (") double quotes it's really helping you.